# Como calcular distancia entre dos puntos usando la api de google con C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, google-api

Espero puedan orientarme, estoy construyendo un sitio en el cual quiero consumir la API de google maps con C#, quiero saber si es posible calcular la distancia entre dos puntos mediante alguna función que ofrezca la API o la tengo que calcular usando alguna función matemática.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Esto podria ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684281/calculating-distance-between-two-points-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacer uso del servicio

[Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)

entonces desde c# basicamente usando `HttpClient` invocas a esa api para obtener el calculo

Aqui se explica genial

[Google Distance Matrix API with HttpClient and Json.NET](https://dujushi.github.io/2016/01/12/Google-Distance-Matrix-API-with-HttpClient-and-Json-NET/)

la idea es usar algo como ser

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var uri = new Uri(GetRequestUrl());

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new Exception("GoogleDistanceMatrixApi failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
    else
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content);
    }
}
```

fijate como se deserializa el json de respuesta